# Extract part of a string using Sed

Tags: sed, extract

I want to extract first part of a string using "Sed" utility. grep and awk are not available in the environment. The input is

"https://jintestexample.example.com/services/get/latest/accounts".

I need to extract the string before "/services". I have to use sed only.

Your help is much appreciated
Thanks,
Jin

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `/services` and whatever follows:

```
echo "https://jintestexample.example.com/services/get/latest/accounts" \
| sed -e 's%/services.*%%'
```