# How to use "sed" to get part of a string?

Tags: regex, sed

### Background

I have a file that has information about my app. I need to get the app's name from that file using the `sed` utility.

### Objective

I have a file with the following lines:

```
app: :my_super_app,
version: "1.4.2",
```

Using `grep` and `cat` I managed to come this far:

```
cat my_file | grep app: | sed -e 's/.*app: "\(:\)",/\1/'
```

Which (wrongly) returns:

`app: :my_super_app`

I want it to return exactly the string `my_super_app`

### Problem

My `sed` command is doing literally nothing. Right now I could remove it and the command would be the same.

What am I doing wrong?

### The research I did:

I have checked some similar questions:

- [Extract part of a string using Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865738/extract-part-of-a-string-using-sed)

But to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command does nothing because it doesn't match. You have no quotes in your string, for example.

Try it like this:

```
sed -e 's/.*app: :\(.*\),/\1/'
```

Works for me :)

Comment: You'll want to use `sed -n` and add a `/p` to print only the matching line.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following once.

```
sed -n '/^app:/s/\(.*:\)\([^,]*\),/\2/p'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
my_super_app
```

EDIT: If you are ok with `awk` then try following.

```
awk -F'[:,]' '/^app:/{print $3}'  Input_file
```

PS: Improvements in your `sed` command will be: NO need to use `cat` and `grep` as `sed` could read Input_file by itself.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, it worked perfectly fine for me, could you please check if you have any control M characters in your file by doing `cat -v Input_file` and let me know?

Comment: doing `cat -v my_file` printed the entire file. No additional info was shown.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, not sure this code worked for me, let me write another alternative for this now.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, if you are ok with `awk` could you please try my EDIT solution now and let me know.

Comment: The input of your awk command is the same of the sed command. Nothing is printed. Still, I shall upvote your answer for trying !

Answer (score 0):

to print ONLY the app name

```
sed -e '/.*app: :\(.*\),.*/!d' -e 's//\1/' my_file
# or
sed -n 's/.*app: :\(.*\),.*/\1/p' my_file
```